# Meeting My Video editor needs

Tags: software-recommendation, video-editor

I plan to work on 2D/3D images so GIMP and Blender seem like the best choice to me but I need a video editor that will compile the two to create my videos.

If anyone needs more guidance, I'm trying to recreate the Star Trek: The Next Generation title sequence but replace the voice over and text with colleagues names as a little joke. Any help would be appreciated!

-Trey

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OpenShot would be the one I would use for the exact same thing. It supports importing multiple images and overlapping them with videos. OpenShot is more focused on creating the video with already existing edited parts (Video, Audio, Images).

I am guessing since you are using Gimp and Blender, you have already edited what you wanted. For Audio maybe Audacity.

[image]

I chose OpenShot because it is faster for what you need, the learning curve is super easy and when creating the final scene it can use all CPUs, so it is very efficient. Imagine it like a powerful Movie Maker.

Comment: Thank you! I'll install it later tonight and give it a whirl :)

Comment: You might also check on kdenlive.

Comment: I was going to mention kdenlive, even on some other similar questions about a month ago, but till this day, kdenlive fails to start, if it does, it has a huge potential on crashing and if I do get to put everything together to the transcode the video, it crashes. I know if offers many features, but I rather stick with something stable, in my case with an Intel i7, 32GB of RAM it should not have an excuse to crash but still does. So I don't mention anything about it to others until I fee it is stable enough.